# Python Trouble getting cursor position (x, y) on desktop

Tags: python, windows-7, cursor-position, pywinauto

I've been looking for ways to find my cursor position and put it on to two variables, x and y. But most answers are outdated and i can't seem to make them work. I would rather if it is in pythons standard librarys or pywinauto. I would also prefer in python 2.7. Thanks.

Comment: We need you to be more specific. First, from the mention of pywinauto, I assume you are talking about a Windows GUI application, but please confirm this. Second, do you mean the position of the mouse pointer on the screen, the position of the mouse pointer relative to some reference rectangle (such as a window or subwindow), the position of the text insertion bar within an editable-text area, or some other "cursor" (in which case please describe it)? Finally, please show at least one thing you already tried and tell us what went wrong with it.

Comment: ("I can't seem to make them work" gives us nothing to go on with.  We need to see the code that doesn't work, and we need to know _what it actually did_ as well as _what you expected it to do_, including the full, exact text of any error messages you got.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [PyMouse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMouse).

```
>>> import pymouse;
>>> mouse = pymouse.PyMouse()
>>> mouse.position()
(288.046875, 396.15625)
>>> mouse.position()
(0.0, 0.0)
>>> mouse.position()
(1439.99609375, 861.2890625)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a ton. I did see pymouse before but i couldn't get the library at first to work. But after i couple minutes of just working at it, I can do what i need to now. Thank you.